# Issue in Lotus Notes with Calendar Entry

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

When users in the Central time zone enter a day of vacation, the day of vacation displays over two days.  The application always adds an additional day.  If a day is requested in the same database by a person in the Eastern timezone, the day only displays as one day which is how it should display, no additional days are added to the display.

Can anyone give me an idea what is not set correctly or what I can do to fix the issue?

Thank you,
jean

Comment: Is this in the user's own calendar? Or in a custom built application?

Answer (score 0):

In the past we had time issuess with the calendar. Not the one you mention. But you might try this.

Go to the users location document. Next go to the tab 'Advanced...' and switch 'Use operating system's time zone settings' from yes to no. See what happens if you set the time zone manually. You might have to restart notes for it to take effect.

In our case the timezone value was corrupted. Although it was not used, it still impacted the calendar.

Good luck.